# Font of my website looks different when viewed on an Iphone 12

Tags: html, dreamweaver, webfonts

hope you are having a good day/night so far.

I am having a bit of problem with the font on my [website](https://tryslimleaf.com/d24/indexwritten.php).

I am making it using Dreamweaver and the fonts that I used are Barlow and Nunito sans. However, when I view it on my friend's iphone 12, the fonts becomes different and looks like Times New Roman.

This doesn't occur on two of my android phones.

I hope somebody can shed a light as to why this is happening. I am trying to search google but can't find a specific answer. I am a beginner so any advice would be very much appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because iPhones don't come with Barlow or Nunito Sans [preinstalled](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/system-fonts/). To fix this, you must tell the browser to load the fonts you need using '[@font-face](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp)'.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try to figure out how to use @font-face. I appreciate your response!